# Правильно рассчитать размер спрайта при масштабировании

Tags: c#, sdl2

Есть класс камеры. В камере есть функция конвертирования из координат мира (декартова плоскость) в координаты экрана (sdl) с учетом размера камеры и aspect ratio:

```
public Point ConvertWorldToScreen(Point worldPoint)
{
    var w = Settings.Resolution.Width; // 800
    var h = Settings.Resolution.Height; // 600
    var ratio = w / h;
    var extents = new Point(ratio * Size, Size); // Size - размер камеры = 5

    var u = (worldPoint.X + extents.X) / (extents.X + extents.X);
    var v = (worldPoint.Y + extents.Y) / (extents.Y + extents.Y);

    return new Point(u * w, (1 - v) * h);
}
```

На мировой плоскости нарисовал сетку, где точка 0x0 находится в центре, а каждое деление равно одному юниту. Один unit по умолчанию равен 100 пикселям.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В точке 0x0 рисую спрайт. Размеры спрайта 128x128 пикселей. При pixelPerUnit = 100 размер спрайта в юнитах 1.28 на 1.28

Спрайт рисую следующей функцией:

```
void Draw(Transform transformTo)
{
    var camera = SceneManager.GetCurrentScene.Camera; // Получаем объект камеры
    var point = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(transformTo.Position - camera.Transform.Position); // Смещаем позицию спрайта относительно позиции камеры в мире.

    var center = new SDL.SDL_FPoint();

    size.Width = rect.Width * transformTo.LocalScale.X; // LocalScale по умолчанию 1x1
    size.Height = rect.Height * transformTo.LocalScale.Y;

    draw_rect.x = (float)(point.X - (size.Width * transformTo.Achor.X)); // Achor по умолчанию 0.5 на 0.5, умножая на размер спрайта получим координаты центра
    draw_rect.y = (float)(point.Y - (size.Height * transformTo.Achor.Y));
    draw_rect.w = (float)size.Width; // вот здесь по идее нужна формула, которая масштабирует спрайт 
    draw_rect.h = (float)size.Height; // и тут

    center.x = (float)(draw_rect.w * transformTo.Achor.X);
    center.y = (float)(draw_rect.h * transformTo.Achor.Y);

    SDL.SDL_RenderCopyExF(Game.RenderContext, srcTexture.TexturePtr, ref srcTexture.Rectangle, ref draw_rect, transformTo.Degrees, ref center, SDL.SDL_RendererFlip.SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```

Если нарисовать спрайт как есть, то он не будет учитывать размер камеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только я не игрался с формулой размера спрайта, так как нужно сделать не получается. В идеале при pixelPerUnit = 128 спрайт размером в 128 пикселей должен идеально по размеру ложиться в квадрат на сетке при любом CameraSize.

На всякий случай код рисования сетки:

```
public static void DrawGrid()
{
    var color = SceneManager.GetCurrentScene.ClearColor;
    var camera = SceneManager.GetCurrentScene.Camera;
    var size = new Graphics.Rect(100, 100);

    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Game.RenderContext, 100, 100, 100, 0);

    for (int i = -size.Width; i <= size.Width; i++)
    {
        var p1 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(i - camera.Transform.Position.X, size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
        var p2 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(i - camera.Transform.Position.X, -size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
        var p3 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.X, i - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
        var p4 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(-size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.X, i - camera.Transform.Position.Y));

        Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_RenderDrawLineF(Game.RenderContext, (float)p1.X, (float)p1.Y, (float)p2.X, (float)p2.Y);
        Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_RenderDrawLineF(Game.RenderContext, (float)p3.X, (float)p3.Y, (float)p4.X, (float)p4.Y);
    }

    var cx1 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(0 - camera.Transform.Position.X, size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
    var cy1 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(0 - camera.Transform.Position.X, -size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
    var cx2 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.X, 0 - camera.Transform.Position.Y));
    var cy2 = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Graphics.Point(-size.Width - camera.Transform.Position.X, 0 - camera.Transform.Position.Y));

    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Game.RenderContext, 200, 200, 200, 0);
    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_RenderDrawLineF(Game.RenderContext, (float)cx1.X, (float)cx1.Y, (float)cy1.X, (float)cy1.Y);
    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Game.RenderContext, 200, 200, 200, 0);
    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_RenderDrawLineF(Game.RenderContext, (float)cx2.X, (float)cx2.Y, (float)cy2.X, (float)cy2.Y);
    Binding.SDL.SDL.SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Game.RenderContext, color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A);
}
```

Comment: Если быть точным, то при `pixelPerUnit = 128`, при размере окна `800x600` и при `CameraSize = 5` `draw_rect.w` должен равнятся `59,9999999999999`.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что сделал следующим образом: беру координаты `(1;0)` и `(0;0)`, конвертирую из декартовой плоскости в плоскость sdl, и из первой координаты вычитаю вторую. В полученной точке координата `X` будет равняться одной единице игрового мира `(unit)`.

```
var unit = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Point(1, 0)).X - camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Point()).X; //единица игрового мира
```

Вычисляя размер спрайта я размер спрайта делю на pixelPerUnit и умножаю на полученный unit.

```
draw_rect.w = (float)(unit * (size.Width / pixelPerUnit));
draw_rect.h = (float)(unit * (size.Height / pixelPerUnit));
```

Функция `Draw` теперь имеет следующий вид:

```
void Draw(Transform transformTo)
{
    var camera = SceneManager.GetCurrentScene.Camera;
    var point = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(transformTo.Position - camera.Transform.Position);

    var center = new SDL.SDL_FPoint();

    size.Width = rect.Width * transformTo.LocalScale.X;
    size.Height = rect.Height * transformTo.LocalScale.Y;

    var unit = camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Point(1, 0)).X - camera.ConvertWorldToScreen(new Point()).X;

    draw_rect.w = (float)(unit * (size.Width / pixelPerUnit));
    draw_rect.h = (float)(unit * (size.Height / pixelPerUnit));

    draw_rect.x = (float)(point.X - (draw_rect.w * transformTo.Achor.X));
    draw_rect.y = (float)(point.Y - (draw_rect.h * transformTo.Achor.Y));

    center.x = (float)(draw_rect.w * transformTo.Achor.X);
    center.y = (float)(draw_rect.h * transformTo.Achor.Y);

    SDL.SDL_RenderCopyExF(Game.RenderContext, srcTexture.TexturePtr, ref srcTexture.Rectangle, ref draw_rect, transformTo.Degrees, ref center, SDL.SDL_RendererFlip.SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```

Я не знаю, насколько это хороший вариант в плане производительности, поэтому вопрос оставлю открытым.